# ios app communicate with C# program

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c

I am currently developing a iPad app, I want the app to talk with a C# program, basically sending data from the app to the C# program.

The C# application is installed on a PC, and they can talk with each other via Wifi, I mean the iPad and the PC will connect to the same Wifi network. I was thinking using socket, but I am not sure whether an objective-c Client socket can talk with a C# Server socket.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are you sending the data through a web server? Or are you trying to communicate via Bluetooth or the 30-pin/Lightning connector?

Comment: What kind of C# program is it? Desktop? Mobile? Web?

Comment: I am developing this iPad app talking to a c# application program installed on a PC, and they can talk with each other via Wifi, I mean the iPad and the PC will connect to the same Wifi network.

Comment: I was thinking using socket, but I am not sure whether an objective-c Client socket can talk with a C# Server socket.

Comment: They can talk, but they should follow the same encoding (UTF-8 or Unicode) to understand each other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the sockets from objetive-c and .NET should be able to talk to each other.

Remember that you will have to convert back and from a byte array to be able to use the sockets. When doing so, make sure that whatever you encode is in binary portable representation, in particular sending strings may result in problems due to character encoding and endianness of the platform.

Answer (score 0):

They can talk to each other but **not** on binary level. That you may want to do is use XML or JSON format to exchange messages. 
If you want them to support some kind of commands like Sum(1,3)

You can use XML

```
<Command name="Sum">
  <Args>
    <Arg type="Int">1</Arg>
    <Arg type="Int">3</Arg>
  </Args>
</Command>
```

This definitely means more work, but once again, they don't support communication on binary level, e.g. you cannot call a method on C# directly.

Don't know your requirements, but if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, use web-services such as WCF or ASP.NET Web-services (the latter is easier to implement for beginners and I believe it's faster, but less features. If you do it for home use on home wifi go for ASP.NET Web-services). On iPad you will need to use a SOAP client.

Cheers,

Comment: Basically, I am developing this iPad app for ordering within a restaurant. The waiter carries this ipad to the table, and open this app, and order what the customer ask to order, after finishing the ordering, the waiter will click the submit button of this app, and all the order information should be sent to a windows Form application which is installed on the PC at the front desk, so the order can be further edited at the front desk PC, and print out the docket. I have finished that ipad app, what I want to do now is achieve the communication between the ipad app and the C# Form application.

Comment: First of all, it's nice that you are doing simple solution for this problem. Now.  I think that WinForms should not be responsible for holding connection to iPads. I would have created a windows service for that. It's more stable (launches automatically after PC restart and more robust as doesn't have UI). The service will take care of information (store it (Possible NoSQL) and when WinForms app is up, it will push orders to it). Or when WinForms app is started it can ask the service for information. Later if you will have a couple of registers it will be easier to have a couple of WinFrm apps